# WCF Service security using Windows or ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, windows, wcf, security, service

I have a WCF Service,

Just trying to toss up between the different security options.
Whether to use ASPNet Membership security on use the windows credentials that are passed to the service

Ist possible to use a hybrid of both?

If so what would be the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Claims-Based authorization** as it works well with whatever security type you choose. It's based on ClaimsAuthenticationManager and ClaimsAuthorizationManager that can easily be plugged in to WCF pipeline.

**Dominick Baier** is leading expert on that field, you may find plenty of resources about WCF and Claims-Based authorization on his web site + his author of many online tutorials:

```
http://leastprivilege.com/
```

Claims-Based authorization is part of **Windows Identity Foundation** and that is the latest security model coming from Microsoft which works with all other MS frameworks.